# Is there a way to use both limitToLast and limitToFirst at the same time?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am trying to make blocks of data (10 each) as query.

The `limitToLast()` and `limitToFirst()` work without each other but crashes the app when together.

```
query = db_reference_type.limitToLast((int) (long_total_buildings - (long_list_page * 10))).limitToFirst(10);

With long_list_page = 0 and long_total_buildings = 10
query = db_reference_type.limitToLast(10).limitToFirst(10);
```

The app just crashes when the program gets to that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to combine `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()` in a single query. You seem to be building a pagination system, and looking for an `offset()` condition, which doesn't exist in Firebase.

It's easier to understand what is possible once you know how Firebase processes your request.

1. When it receives a query at a location, Firebase retrieves an index of the items on that location on the property that you order the query on (or on the key if no order is specified).
2. It then finds the value that you've indicated you want to start returning items from. So this is a value of the property that you order the query on (or on the key if no order is specified).
3. It then finds the value that you've indicated you want to end returning items at. This too is a value of the property that you order the query on (or on the key if no order is specified).
4. So at this point the database has a range of values in the index, and by association the keys of the items matching those values.
5. It then clips the items in the range by either the number of items from the start (if you use `limitToFirst()`) or from the end (if you use `limitToLast`).

And then finally it returns the remaining items that match all criteria.

Note that the value you pass to `limitToFirst`/`limitToLast` is only used in the last step of this process. It is not used in step 3, which is what you seem to be trying.

Comment: So I will try this algorithm: initialize the first page with limitToFirst(11) storing the previous key as null and next key from the last item.  With those keys depending on if I turn the page forwards or backwards with exceptions, startAt(next_key).limitToFirst(11) or endAt(prev_key).limitToLast(11) and then update the keys.